# How can I change 4 cubes color in one script in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm creating the **Simon Says game** in **Unity**, I'm looking for a way to change the cubes' colors together, one after the other. For instance :

**Cube 1** : Dark-RED changes to RED

**Cube 2** : Dark-Blue changes to BLUE

**Cube 3** : Dark-Yellow changes to YELLOW

**Cube 4** : Dark-Green changes to GREEN.

The change is random.

Answer (score 0):

You could but the four cubes inside a GameObject and put a script on the parent.

In the main script you get a random number between 0-3 and then use it to get the Cube at the position using GetChild then get the renderer of this Cube and change the color to whatever you want.

Something like this. (This code is not finished but should give you an idea). It is in C# but should be similar in Javascript

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.Next(0, 3);
Gambeobject child = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(index).gameObject;
Renderer rend = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend.material.SetColor("_SpecColor", Color.red);
```

Edit for Gameobject:
Everything is a gameobject just use "create empty" and put your 4 Cubes there as childs. Put the script on the Parent which is in the image marked

[image]

Comment: I'm new to using Unity but I think I understand what you're saying, how do I put the four cubes inside one GameObject?

Comment: @Hadh Just create an empty game object, then drag and drop your cubes onto it